# I tried every way to get rid of the .html url in .htaccess and it just will not work

Tags: html, .htaccess, web

I've tried to use multiple variations of code found on stackoverflow to try to get rid of the .html thing from urls. And yes, I did change all of the hrefs to without the .html extension and I get a 404 error every time. I am using vscode live server, but I have also tried transferring the code over to my host and it wouldn't work either. Typing the page name with the .html works, but removing it doesn't. I've tried every copy and paste code I could find from stackoverflow and it just would not work.

Comment: Sounds you change the file extension, the name should be pointed to exact name or  else it can not be found - 404. Are you trying to hide the file name from address bar?

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried?

Comment: I've tried things like changing <li><a href="/projects.html">PROJECTS</a></li> to                     <li><a href="/projects">PROJECTS</a></li>. And then in the .htaccess file, essentially RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
But I've tried like 20 variations of this code. I have no idea why it's not working? It's working for literally everyone else

Comment: Could it be that you forgot to activate the interpretation of dynamic configuration files (".htaccess")? Or that you placed that file at the wrong location? Or that it is not readable by the http server? You will need to start debugging yourself. Start out with the http server's error log file. What does it contain? _And please do not add details in comments, add them to the question itself..._

Answer (score 0):

.htaccess file is a config file for Apache server, not VSCode Live Server.